# I have this for my homework about moment generating functions

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Consider the following the continuous RVs X1, X2, Y, and Z: 
X1 ~ U(10, 20), 
X2 ~ U(10, 20), 
Y = X1 + X2, 
Z = Y + 20, 
a. What is the MGF of Z?
b. Draw the pdf of Z.
c. Use the MGF of Z to get its mean. 
d. Find P( Z < 50). Shade the appropriate area that corresponds to the said probability

I have arrived at an answer for A but I can't figure out the distribution which makes it hard for me to answer the following questions.

Comment: I found that Mz = ((e^10s-1/10s)^2)(e^40s). But from the table for MGF of known distributions, I can't place this particular MGF among them.

Comment: Consider the MGF at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution with $c-b=b-a$

Answer (score 0):

If it were given that $X_1,X_2$ are independent, then you can use the basic result on the moment-generating function of the sum of two independent random variables.

Next you have
\begin{align}
& M_{Y+20} (t) =\operatorname{E}(e^{t(Y+20)}) = \operatorname{E}(e^{tY} e^{20t}) \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{20t} \operatorname{E}(e^{tY}) \text{ because $e^{20t}$ is constant, i.e. not random} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{20t} M_Y(t).
\end{align}

Comment: yes, I have arrived at that and Mz = ((e^10s-1/10s)^2)(e^40s). Btw, sorry, I don't know how to properly write a formula here.